# React images not rendering when sourced from API and mapped to a variable

Tags: javascript, react-native

Firstly, thanks to this community for helping me solve hundreds of coding questions the past few years. Thankfully before now I have found almost every answer I needed here without having to post!

Unfortunately this one has me completely stumped. I am coding a new app in React Native and after loading a JSON response from the an API, I can not get the images to render after mapping the result to a variable and then rendering it.

I have checked that the image URL is received correctly via the JSON response and map function by including it in a text view. I've also confirmed it is 'https" and not 'http'.

I've tried to implement numerous methods mentioned on these forums to ensure the image loads but for whatever reason I just get the text field and not the image. The Image container is there but just empty. When I put a URL from the response directly into the Image 'uri' field it works fine. The snippet of the offending code is below which shows no errors and works when I run it on Snack with the full code.

```js
function buildView (data){
  var itemData = data.map((d) => 
      <View style={{padding: 10}}>
        <Image
          source={{uri: '{d.galleryURL}'}}
          key={d.itemID}
          style={{width: 200 , height: 140}}
          loadingIndicatorSource=<ActivityIndicator />
          resizeMode={'contain'}
        />
        <Text key={d.title}>Title: {d.title}</Text>
      </View>
  );
  return(itemData);
}

if (this.state.isLoading!=true) {
  var dataView = buildView(this.state.dataSource);
  return(
      <ScrollView
        style={{ flex: 1}}
        scrollEnabled={true}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
        >
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 60 }}>
            {dataView}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

If anyone can help identify what I have missed in my code it would be appreciated. My only suspicion is something to do with it not re-rendering but I can't see why at the moment.

Comment: I believe, for the component Image the attribute source does not need quotes  source={{uri: {d.galleryURL}}}

Comment: ^ No braces either, just `source={{ uri: d.galleryURL }}`

Comment: Just source={{uri: {d.galleryURL}}} or source={{ uri: d.galleryURL }}

Comment: When I try {d.galleryURL} I get the following error: ESLint: (40:31) Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," which point to the d.

When I try it as just d.galleryURL it gives me an error on Android (wont load at all) and on iOS it creates an alert asking for access to the local gallery. 

I had tried both options before with no luck so I guess the d.galleryURL is causing the issue then?

Answer (score 0):

'{d.galleryURL}' is literally a string with value equal **{d.galleryURL}** in Javascript. Obviously no images will show with that value. If your `galleryURL` is working, you should be able to display it with:

```
<Image
    source={{uri: d.galleryURL}}
    key={d.itemID}
    style={{width: 200 , height: 140}}
    loadingIndicatorSource=<ActivityIndicator />
    resizeMode={'contain'}
/>
```

Comment: When I try it as just d.galleryURL it gives me an error on Android (wont load at all) and on iOS it creates an alert asking for access to the local gallery. 

I had tried both options before with no luck so I guess the d.galleryURL is causing the issue then?

Comment: "Uncaught Error: Error while updating property 'src' of a view managed by RCTImageView". I've double checked and if I add the d.galleryURL to a Text view, it's prints fine.

Comment: Thank you for you answer as it has now managed to help me find the source of the error. The URL was stored in a sub-array, which I only found by implementing the above and getting the Android error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Seems that whilst the text string would show the URL fine, it was in fact part of a sub-array within the JSON response. So once I changed the variable to `d.galleryURL[0]` it worked fine.

I can now repair the hole in the wall due to me bashing my head against it...